# How to do array parameters in prisma?

Tags: node.js, express, prisma

How can I do querying like this in prisma?

```
http://localhost://3000/api/users?[param1]=[value1]&[param2]=[value2]&......
```

Or param1, param2....can be from different model

Answer (score 0):

req.query is object that contain query string that enter in the url and you access with `req.query`

```
const age = req.query.param1;
const score = req.query.param2;

const users = await prisma.users.findMany ({
  where: {
    age  , 
    score
  }
});
```